# Multiple hosts name possible on samba server side?

Tags: samba, hosts

I want to use 2 hostnames to access my samba server.

[such as like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umGzI.png)

I mean, On my local network, I want to access the same server (everything is similar) but with 2 different names on network.

Is this possible?

For example my server hostname = Name1
I can access that server as `smb://name1/....` or `\\name1\...` (On Windows)
Also I want to use a second name such as example `Name2`
So I want to access the same server as `smb://name2/....` or `\\name2\...` (On Windows) too?

I did try something on `/etc/hosts` file... But maybe that was wrong...
Didn't work...

This is what I did try

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Name1
127.0.1.1   Name2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: The only issue I can see here is that having `smb://SERVER` or `smb://PC` on the same system is that they will point to the same thing.  You can make shares on the Samba server so that only specific users have access to the specific shares.  There is no way to add a shortcut into the `/etc/hosts` file that will point to anything other than the hostname or IP address itself.

Comment: The line needs to be like this `127.0.1.1  PC  SERVER`.  Your 3rd line overwrites the 2nd line.